# how to import functions from different file when deploying flows to aws step function?

Tags: netflix-metaflow

I have the following folder structure:

- metaflow project/

  - flow_a.py
  - flow_b.py
  - helpers.py

Flow a and flow b are separated independent flows, but there some functions that occurs both in a and b,
For avoiding duplicate code I made helper function in `helpers.py` which I import in both flow a and b.
My problem is, when I deploy on AWS step function with `python flow_a.py step-functions create`
The flow is created but `helpers.py` not, therefore when I try to import in my steps function from the helpers.py the code fail,

What is the correct approach to address this problem?
Thx

Comment: try importing from the helpers module within your steps instead of the top of the flow script